# HTML Multiselect to choose more than 50000 values using javascript and ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

In my project we have multiselect option which contains more than 50000 records, using ajax based upon search fetch data from server and shown to user(no problem).There is an option to select all records called **check all** if user selects check all option then browser getting hanged because in hidden i post all the values which are selected ,(ie) reason for browser hang so please suggest me how to get all selected values without any problem

Comment: 50000 records and you want browser not to hang itself!!!

Comment: Show us the code for the select all function so we can discuss any improvement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the user checks the option, simply hide the multiselect and evaluate the value of the `select_all` input on the server side. If you want to use a link (and not an `<input type="checkbox">`), you can create an input element with `type="hidden"` to store the user's "select all" preference in.

Comment: Dear phihag, thanks if i use `type=hidden` to collect the selected values for instance if user selects 40000 records how we put the 40000 selected values in ** hidden ** it is possible??

Comment: @user1081047 Nope, that's not what I meant (although that would probably work fine, too). I meant creating a binary hidden element that indicates whether all items should be selected.

Comment: sorry for asking this mr.phihag i am very new to this what is meant by binary hidden

Comment: @user1081047 In JavaScript (with jQuery), create the element like this when the user clicks the "Select all" link: `$('<input type="hidden" name="select_all" value="on">').appendTo($('form'))`. Then, on the server side, evaluate the value of the `select_all` POST parameter. If it is set, select all possible records (on the server side). Otherwise (and only then) evaluate the `records` parameter as you currently do. That allows you to avoid transferring  the whole list of records to the client for all the users who click `select all`.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of things that could be wrong. Off the top of my head:

1. Are you sure you need to update 50,000 records simultaneously?
2. Are you combining the updates into one request? 50,000 requests will certainly hang a browser.
3. If request size is an issue, you could alternatively submit id ranges (so `?add=10,11,12,13,14,15,16` becomes `?add=10-16`)

Comment: Dear skier, Ya i want to update records based upon the user selection if user choose 1000 values then i want to update 1000 records if 5000 like it goes on.... for point no 2 ajax request is only for showing values to user after user selectsvalue only one request is used to post...

Comment: Ok, then unless the issue is #3 then the issue is simply the javascript manipulating the DOM, and the solution would be what phihag said.